# Como hacer funcionar el Live Reload en Netbeans con Spring Boot

Tags: java, mvc, spring-boot, servidor

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Estoy empezando en Spring Boot y tengo las dependencias de Live Reload Server dentro de mi proyecto y me funciona correctamente el servidor de Apache Tomcat. Sin embargo, para ver los cambios que realizo, tengo que reiniciar el server, a pesar de que el Live Reload Server este funcionando. Es algo frustrante porque no puedo encontrar la solución a este problema. Lo que quiero es que al guardar los archivos en Netbeans, solo sea necesario refrescar la pagina.

PD: Si guardo los cambios desde Netbeans, pero aún así no funciona.

```
2023-06-07T00:02:28.940-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 4992 (C:\Users\obred\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\P1\target\classes started by obred in C:\Users\obred\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\P1)
2023-06-07T00:02:28.995-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-07T00:02:29.373-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-07T00:02:29.379-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-07T00:02:34.970-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-07T00:02:35.025-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-07T00:02:35.029-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-07T00:02:35.480-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-07T00:02:35.495-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6106 ms
2023-06-07T00:02:36.703-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2023-06-07T00:02:37.558-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-06-07T00:02:37.714-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-07T00:02:37.747-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 10.956 seconds (process running for 13.304)
2023-06-07T00:03:02.225-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-07T00:03:02.229-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-07T00:03:02.303-05:00  INFO 4992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 72 ms
```

Controlador

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 *
 * @author obred
 */

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "home")
    public String saludor() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Vista

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Hola Mundo Spring</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Resultado que lanza a pesar que ye le hice cambios, guarde y refresque la página:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no se que pasa, porque todo aparenta estar bien con mi configuración. Corren ambos servers pero no funciona uno.

Comment: Dentro de ¿cuál folder se encuentra tu vista?

Comment: Dentro de template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero asegurarte que tus recursos se encuentren dentro de alguno de los siguientes folders:

- `/META-INF/maven`
- `/META-INF/resources`
- `/resources`
- `/static`
- `/public`
- `/templates`

Ya que solo los recursos que se encuentren dentro de alguno de esos folders activarán un live reload*.

Asegúrate que el nombre de tu folder coincida con alguno de los anteriores mencionados, si esto es así, otra opción que podrías probar sería instalar la extensión de [LiveReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remotelivereload/jlppknnillhjgiengoigajegdpieppei?hl=en-GB) para Google Chrome**.

*[Excluding resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude)

**[Live Reload](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools#live-reload)